# Invalid character identifier error within a data dictionary

Tags: python, syntax-error, data-dictionary, invalid-characters

I am trying to make dataframe for a final project at school. I have already calculated the numbers for everything, however, Python is not happy with the data dictionary that I am making. I have tried making the numbers into strings but the same syntax error kept popping up and I'm not sure on what to do about it.

```
# The 10 min average PM 2.5 time in the interval of the traffic signal 

 avg_pm10_traffic_joint= {'Average Cycle Length (Min)': [2.944444, 2.888889, 2.277778, 2.166667, 2.055556],
                          'PM 2.5 (10 Min Avg)':[45.13, 42.05, 40.75, 40.14, 39.31],
                          'Average PM 2.5 per Traffic Signal Cycle Rate (Rate = 2.944 (Min))': [13.286, 12.379, 11.996, 11.817, 11.572‬],
                          'Average PM 2.5 per Traffic Signal Cycle Rate (Rate = 2.899 (Min))': [13.083‬, 12.190, 11.813, 11.636, 11.395‬],
                          'Average PM 2.5 per Traffic Signal Cycle Rate (Rate = 2.277 (Min))': [10.276, 9.574, 9.278‬, 9.139‬, 8.950‬],
                          'Average PM 2.5 per Traffic Signal Cycle Rate (Rate = 2.166 (Min))': [9.775‬, 9.108, 8.826‬, 8.694‬, 8.514‬ ],
                          'Average PM 2.5 per Traffic Signal Cycle Rate (Rate = 2.055 (Min))': [9.274‬, 8.641‬, 8.374‬, 8.248, 8.078‬] 
                     }
```

It gives:

```
Output: File "<ipython-input-8-a3a71d8fb5de>", line 6
'Average PM 2.5 per Traffic Signal Cycle Rate (Rate = 2.944 (Min))': [13.286‬, 12.379, 11.996, 11.817, 11.572‬],                                                                                                                                                             
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

The arrow pointing to the error is at the first comma after 13.286 (I just couldn't get the arrow lined in the body of this message).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I look at this code in Vim, I see <202c> periodically throughout your lists. That is what is causing the problem. You may want to look at it with a different text editor in order to remove those factors.

Try copying this :

```
avg_pm10_traffic_joint= {'Average Cycle Length (Min)': [2.944444, 2.888889, 2.277778, 2.166667, 2.055556],
    'PM 2.5 (10 Min Avg)':[45.13, 42.05, 40.75, 40.14, 39.31],
    'Average PM 2.5 per Traffic Signal Cycle Rate (Rate = 2.944 (Min))': [13.286, 12.379, 11.996, 11.817, 11.572
    'Average PM 2.5 per Traffic Signal Cycle Rate (Rate = 2.899 (Min))': [13.083, 12.190, 11.813, 11.636, 11.395
    'Average PM 2.5 per Traffic Signal Cycle Rate (Rate = 2.277 (Min))': [10.276, 9.574, 9.278, 9.139, 8.950
    'Average PM 2.5 per Traffic Signal Cycle Rate (Rate = 2.166 (Min))': [9.775, 9.108, 8.826, 8.694, 8.514],
    'Average PM 2.5 per Traffic Signal Cycle Rate (Rate = 2.055 (Min))': [9.274, 8.641, 8.374, 8.248, 8.078] 
}
```

Comment: I would add that "\u200b is the [ZERO WIDTH SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm)"

Comment: Oh ok, I've been using jupyter while coding, but i'll definitely give this a try. Thanks!